# Middleman :relative_assets compatibility with :directory_indexes

Tags: middleman

I'm having some issues with Middleman 3.0 that I'm confused by. I am building my site with `activate :relative_assets` and `activate :directory_indexes`, the builder doesn't realize that the file is nested one level deep and outputs the wrong relative paths for images, javascript files, stylesheets, etc. What I'm confused about is that this issue was apparently fixed here: https://github.com/middleman/middleman/issues/361. I installed Middleman with the `gem install middleman` command, plus I just ran `gem update`, so I'd think that I'd have the latest version. Does anybody have some ideas what I'm doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you activate :directory_indexes you need to have your site [running under a webserver](http://middlemanapp.com/pretty-urls/).

Probably the easiest way to do this would be to use (Apache) virtual hosts.

If you use Apache, you can also use mod rewrite to rewrite the urls accodingly, but this may be a little harder.

You could also make use of the `base`-tag with a proper href (like `http://localhost/yoursubfolder`), although it might be a little cumbersome to keep this in sync between your dev environment and for example your live-server.